# Add 2 input values and show total Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully, this makes sense. I have 2 input fields that will add together and spit out the total. I have that part working. here is the issue, let say I put $200 in input1 and $1000 in input2, but then I want to change input1 to $300. The total will come out to $301 instead of $1300. Here is my code.

```
$('#additionalPayment, #currentPayment').keyup(function() {
  updateTotal();
});

var updateTotal = function() {
    var input1 = parseInt($('#additionalPayment').val());
    var input2 = parseInt($('#currentPayment').val());
    var inputTotal = input1 + input2;

    if (isNaN(inputTotal)) {
        $('.totalPay').text('-');
    } else {
        $('.totalPay').text(formatMoney(inputTotal, 0));
    }
};
```

Comment: If you would, please edit your question and hit Ctrl+M to bring up the on site editor.  You can make a working example of the issue that way.

Comment: you're missing the function formatMoney. It's called in your code but you haven't provided it.

Comment: are you actually putting in the $ in the input, if so you need to either strip the dollar sign and validate that the number is not NaN

Comment: the issue was with something completely different that was causing this script to not work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something bad happening in your `formatMoney` method the rest seems to work as expected.

For example:

```
$('#additionalPayment, #currentPayment').keyup(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

var updateTotal = function () {
    var input1 = parseInt($('#additionalPayment').val());
    var input2 = parseInt($('#currentPayment').val());
    var inputTotal = input1 + input2;

    if (isNaN(inputTotal)) {
        $('.totalPay').text('-');
    } else {
        $('.totalPay').text(formatMoney(inputTotal , 2));
    }
};

var formatMoney = function (val, places) {
    return ('$' + val.toFixed(places));
}
```